# Как записать в textarea значение переменной php?

Tags: php, html, textarea

Как можно записать в textarea значение переменной php?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

При выводе переменной в textarea (впрочем, как и в любой другой input и в целом на страницу html) нужно учитывать, что в переменной могут содержаться символы, которые сломают структуру документа, если они не экранированы. Например, `>, <, ", '`.

Иными словами, если переменная содержит в себе текст `</textarea>`, то будучи выведена в форму в чистом виде, она сломает форму.

Поэтому перед выводом в форму переменную нужно обработать с помощью [htmlspecialchars():](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.htmlspecialchars.php)

```
<textarea><?php echo htmlspecialchars($var); ?></textarea>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<textarea> <?php echo $text ?> </textarea>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<textarea><?= $var ?></textarea>
```